# Conspiracy of calendar makers?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My calendar on my phone reminded me that today I have "תענית אסתר" on my schedule. As far as I remember, I'm not supposed to meet Esther to play tennis until next week. I looked at my wall calendar and there it was in print, "תענית אסתר"! What's going on here? Is there a conspiracy of calendar makers to try to make me go to the tennis court on the wrong day? Why would they do such a thing?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I think it actually says, "Tiniest Esther."

Comment: Make sure you hide the tennis ball doubly well while playing, so it can't be found until Purim.

Answer (score 1):

It must be that the Y2K bug finally hit your calendar. You got to change the date on your calendar to 2000 again and then it should stop dreying you a kup.